# Dynamic form validation with RxAndroid

Tags: forms, validation, rx-android

I'm developing an Android application. I would like to use RxAndroid for form validation. I have done a lot of research on the internet but did not find a guide to take me through. Please help me out with how i can go about with the same, possibly with a small example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial, looks great: [Reactive Forms with RxAndroid](https://www.vokal.io/labs/reactive-forms-with-rxandroid)

First, add [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) to your project

> RxBinding has a built in method for doing this,
>   RxTextView.textChanges(). It takes a EditText and returns an
>   Observable emmitting a CharSequence on each character change.

```
 mInputLayout.setError("Invalid Credit Card Number")
    Observable<Boolean> creditCardObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(mCreditCardInput)
            .map(inputText -> (inputText.length() == 0) || inputText.toString().matches("credit card regex here"))
            .distinctUntilChanged();
    creditCardObservable.subscribe(isValid -> mInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(!isValid));
```

Repeat the process with more values, like:

```
 mCreditCardInputLayout.setError("Invalid Email);
Observable<Boolean> emailObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(mEmailInput)
        .map(inputText -> (inputText.length() == 0) || inputText.toString().matches("credit card regex here"))
        .distinctUntilChanged();

emailObservable.subscribe(isValid -> mCreditCardInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(isValid))
```

And then we can enable the button when the values are valid:

```
    Observable.combineLatest(
                creditCardObservable,
                emailObservable,
                (creditValid, emailValid) -> creditValid && emailValid)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribe(valid -> mSubmit.setEnabled(valid));
```

[image]

Optional [retrolambda library](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)

Comment: Much better, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this post.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What about lambda expression support?

Comment: @Chitrang for lambda support im using retrolambda -> https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda